# Mocking functions retrieved from __getattr__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm automating some repository operations and I'm using [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for this job. Let's simplify things and assume I'd like to assert whether my function called `pull` method on the repository. Code below:

```
from pytest_mock import MockFixture
from git import Git, Repo

repo = Repo('/Users/Jatimir/path/to/repo')

def pull() -> None:
    repo.git.pull()
```

However, I noticed that `Git` class is somewhat special and doesn't implement `pull`. Instead, it "delegates" all the traffic to `__getattr__` which uses another method that does the job.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    ...
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

My question is how to approach testing this? I'm using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) with [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) that provides a `mocker` fixture and here are my attempts:

```
def test_pull1(mocker: MockFixture) -> None:
    pull_mock = mocker.MagicMock(name='pull')
    getattr_mock = mocker.MagicMock(name='__getattr__', return_value=pull_mock)

    mocker.patch.object(Git, '__getattr__', getattr_mock)
    pull()
    pull_mock.assert_called_once_with()


def test_pull2(mocker: MockFixture) -> None:
    pull_mock = mocker.Mock(name='pull')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'pull':
            return pull_mock

    mocker.patch.object(Git, '__getattr__', __getattr__)
    pull()
    pull_mock.assert_called_once_with()
```

They both work, but I feel like there is a better way and maybe my approach to testing this is wrong.

Comment: The fact that `Git` uses `__getattr__` is an *implementation detail*; just mock the `pull` method as if they implemented it the normal way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's the first thing I tried and I was getting `AttributeError: <class 'git.cmd.Git'> does not have the attribute 'pull'` :/ with `patch.object`, but thanks to your comment I tried to manually assign a Mock to Git.pull and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You have to pass `create=True` to get the patch methods to replace attributes that don't exist.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow :D that's such a simple solution, it works perfectly. It's great that I can use `patch.object` instead of my dirty solutions. You can add it as an answer, so I can accept it (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) who instructed me to use `create` argument I managed to achieve what I wanted with the following code:

```
def test_pull(mocker: MockFixture) -> None:
    m = mocker.patch.object(Git, 'pull', create=True)
    pull()
    m.assert_called_once_with()
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) explaining what `create=True` does:

> By default patch() will fail to replace attributes that don’t exist. If you pass in create=True, and the attribute doesn’t exist, patch will create the attribute for you when the patched function is called, and delete it again afterwards.